# Rename Services & Application in Failover Cluster Manager Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-clustering

```
PS C:\Users\sup> Get-ClusterGroup | Where-Object {$_.name -ilike "*scvmm*"}

Name                       Owner                         State
----                      ---------                      -----
scvmm..rtrtry.exported      n01                           Offline
scvmm..rtrtry566.exported   n02                           Offline
```

Hi All, i wanted to rename the services & application in Failover cluster manager which have the words `scvmm` & `exported` in it using powershell, for example the above names should be changed to `..rtrtry.` & `..rtrtry566.`, could some one help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the objects you want with a regex match and set the name property:

```
get-clustergroup | 
    where {$_.Name -match "scvmm\.(.*)\.exported"} | 
    foreach {$_.Name = $matches[1]}
```

Comment: Make sure you run it in an elevated prompt.  And it's important that it is executed as one command rather than splitting the pipeline into multiple commands.